# Call to a member function count() on null

Tags: php, laravel, insert

When I'm going to add data an error appears "Call to a member function count() on null"

View

```
                @foreach ($data as $row)
                <tr>
                  <td>{{ $row->customer}}</td>
                  <td>{{ $row->vessel}}</td>
                  <td>{{ $row->scopejob}}</td>
                  <td>{{ $row->pergantian_sparepart}}</td>
                  <td>{{ $row->teknisi}}</td>
                  <td>{{ $row->tahun}}</td>
                  <td>{{ $row->keterangan}}</td>
                  <td>{{ $row->images->count()}}</td>
                  <td>{{ $row->files->count()}}</td>
                  <td>
                    <a href={{route('data.images',$row->id)}} type="button" class="btn btn-info m-1">FOTO</a>
                    <a href={{route('data.files',$row->id)}} type="button" class="btn btn-info m-1">FILE</a>
                    <a href="/show_rekap/{{ $row->id}}" class="btn btn-warning m-1">EDIT</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger delete m-1" data-id="{{ $row->id}}" data-customer="{{ $row->customer}}" >DELETE</a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
```

Controller `rekap`:

```
    public function insert_rekap(Request $request) {
        // dd($request->all());
        $this -> validate($request,[
            'customer'=>'required',
            'vessel'=>'required',
            'scopejob'=>'required',
            'pergantian_sparepart'=>'required',
            'teknisi'=>'required',
            'tahun'=>'required',
            'keterangan'=>'required'
        ]);
        $data = rekap::create($request->all());
        if($request->hasFile("images")){
            $images=$request->file("images");
            foreach($images as $image){
                $imageName=time().'_'.$image->getClientOriginalName();
                $request['rekap_id']=$data->id;
                $request['image']=$imageName;
                $image->move(public_path("/images_rekap"),$imageName);
                Image_rekap::create($request->all());

            }if($request->hasFile("files")){
                $files=$request->file("files");
                foreach($files as $file){
                    $fileName=time().'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
                    $request['rekap_file_id']=$data->id;
                    $request['file']=$fileName;
                    $file->move(\public_path("/rekap_file"),$fileName);
                    file_rekap::create($request->all());
                }
            }
        }
        return redirect()->route('rekap')->with('success','Data Berhasil Ditambahkan');
    }
```

but the data is successfully entered into the database, and what steps should I take to correct the error

Comment: use count() function or check with is null

Comment: first check $row->images !empty & use count($row->images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error tells you that `images` or `files` or both variables are null, looks like you don't use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

quick and dirty way is to use [optional](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-optional) helper

```php
<td>{{ optional($row->images)->count()}}</td>
<td>{{ optional($row->files)->count()}}</td>
```

---

if you need only count then better approach is to use eloquent [counting related models](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#relationship-counting-and-custom-select-statements)

```php
// controller
$data = rekap::withCount(['images', 'files'])
  // other selecting rules
  //->where ...
  ->get();
return view('view_name', ['data'=>$data]);
```

now in every $row of $data you have fields `images_count` and `files_count`

```php
<td>{{ $row->images_count }}</td>
<td>{{ $row->files_count }}</td>
```

also you can rename count variables like `rekap::withCount(['images as imagesCount', 'files as filesCount'])`

```php
<td>{{ $row->imagesCount }}</td>
<td>{{ $row->filesCount }}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<td>{{ $row->images ? $row->images->count() : '' }}</td>
```